# How to publish Table content on confluence wiki

Tags: rest, go, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I have some data which is in table format (generated using Go https://github.com/olekukonko/tablewriter) API, I am trying to print the table content as it is on the confluence wiki from the rest API. But while passing it to the body Its format got disturbed and not able to print the table. Please suggest how to do the same for this use case.

**Output**:
+------------+------------+-------------------+ | name | sample | sample2 | +------------+------------+-------------------+ | test-1 | 20 | 1 | | test_4 | 20 | 1 | +------------+------------+-------------------+

```
**data**:
+------------+------------+-------------------+
| Name       |  sample    | sample2           |
+------------+------------+-------------------+
| test-1     |         20 |                 1 |
| test_4     |         20 |                 1 |
+------------+------------+-------------------+

type Payload struct {
    Type    string  `json:"type"`
    Title   string  `json:"title"`
    Space   Space   `json:"space"`
    Version Version `json:"version"`
    Body    Body    `json:"Body"`
}
type Space struct {
    Key string `json:"key"`
}
type Version struct {
    Number int `json:"number"`
}
type Storage struct {
    Value          string `json:"value"`
    Representation string `json:"representation"`
}
type Body struct {
    Storage Storage `json:"storage"`
}

func UpdateWiki(data string) int {
    Payload_data := Payload{
        Type: "page", Title: "",
        Space:   Space{Key: ""},
        Version: Version{Number: 4},
        Body:    Body{Storage{Value: data, Representation: "storage"}},
    }
    payloadBytes, err := json.Marshal(Payload_data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    body := bytes.NewReader(payloadBytes)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", "https://wiki.xyz.io/rest/api/content/xxxxx", body)
    //fmt.Println(err)
    dump, err := httputil.DumpRequest(req, true)
    fmt.Printf("%s", dump)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)

    }

    req.SetBasicAuth("", "")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    fmt.Println(resp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)

    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    return resp.StatusCode
}
```